# How to train neural network for UK number plates in MATLAB?

Tags: android, matlab, image-processing, neural-network, automatic-license-plate-recognition

I came across this [project](https://github.com/donnguyen/UIT-ANPR) on GitHub which is an automatic number plate recognition software for Vietnamese number plates.

After looking through the content, I discovered a file in the assets folder called "neural_net.ser".

Am I right in assuming this is a trained neural network, if yes, all I need to do is train a neural network for uk number plates, how can I achieve that using MATLAB?

Out of curiosity, how long will it take to train?

Comment: Your question is generally very broad.  If you have access to Matlab's Neural Network Toolbox you might begin by working through some tutorial examples.

The length of training time will depend on the amount of training data, your validation methods, the complexity of your network and your available computing resources.

Comment: Will I get a .ser file as well once I do as you state?

Comment: No ser.  In MATLAB, neural networks are an object which can be exported to a *.mat file.

Comment: Alright, thanks for your response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I can tell, the neural_net.ser has been created for use with the com.hazuu.uitanpr.neural-package (which is also included at https://github.com/donnguyen/UIT-ANPR/blob/master/src/com/hazuu/uitanpr/neural/KohonenNetwork.java).

The creator of this code, Jeff Heaton, has also created "Encog", a machine learning network that also creates neural networks.

My quess would be, that you should have a look at Encog in order to create your own neural-network for UK-numberplates.

http://www.heatonresearch.com/encog